Any new and nice way to plot phylogenetic tree in LaTeX from an external csv file?
To start off, I have no code to show as I didn't have even a single semi-positive run. I tried everything from basic trees, to trying to be smart with coordinate plots, but failed spectacularly.
I have read all previous messages here on working with phylogenetic trees, but they seem to work well with a small number of elements. (For example: How to draw phylogenetic tree?, Drawing phylogenetic tree, Time axis for forest phylogenetic tree). I have a relatively large dataset that I wish to work with. My belief is that this graph can be made a lot prettier and will be more flexible for further changes in LaTeX than in R using ggtree.
This is the output (generated in R) that I sort of want to replicate in LaTeX:

Here is the content of the Data.csv using which R is able to plot this graph:
"parent","node","branch.length","label","isTip","x","y","branch","angle"
192,1,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros affinis",TRUE,50,131,47.2454977668133,307.058823529412
193,2,12.6124637082775,"Actinocyclus sp. (in: diatoms)",TRUE,50,114,43.6937681458612,272.268907563025
192,3,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros hirtisetus",TRUE,50,132,47.2454977668133,308.571428571429
192,4,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros curvisetus",TRUE,50,130,47.2454977668133,305.546218487395
192,5,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros debilis",TRUE,50,129,47.2454977668133,304.033613445378
192,6,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros diadema",TRUE,50,128,47.2454977668133,302.521008403361
192,7,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros didymus",TRUE,50,127,47.2454977668133,301.008403361345
192,8,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros eibenii",TRUE,50,126,47.2454977668133,297.983193277311
192,9,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros lorenzianus",TRUE,50,125,47.2454977668133,296.470588235294
192,10,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros protuberans",TRUE,50,124,47.2454977668133,294.957983193277
192,11,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros pseudocurvisetus",TRUE,50,123,47.2454977668133,293.445378151261
192,12,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros radicans",TRUE,50,122,47.2454977668133,291.932773109244
192,13,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros seiracanthus",TRUE,50,121,47.2454977668133,290.420168067227
219,14,9.07369660419028,"Detonula pumila",TRUE,50,118,45.4631516979049,282.857142857143
189,15,9.07369660419028,"Ditylum brightwellii",TRUE,50,96,45.4631516979049,225.378151260504
190,16,16.1843752478482,"Hemiaulus hauckii",TRUE,50,99,41.9078123760759,234.453781512605
233,17,5.50900446637347,"Lithodesmium undulatum",TRUE,50,97,47.2454977668133,228.403361344538
233,18,5.50900446637347,"Lithodesmium variabile",TRUE,50,98,47.2454977668133,232.941176470588
197,19,5.50900446637347,"Odontella aurita",TRUE,50,100,47.2454977668133,237.478991596639
197,20,5.50900446637347,"Odontella longicruris",TRUE,50,101,47.2454977668133,240.504201680672
218,21,5.50900446637347,"Skeletonema sp.",TRUE,50,116,47.2454977668133,276.806722689076
219,22,9.07369660419028,"Thalassiosira sp.",TRUE,50,119,45.4631516979049,285.882352941176
188,23,12.6124637082775,"Limnospira fusiformis",TRUE,50,2,43.6937681458612,6.05042016806723
236,24,0.168512719242249,"Scenedesmus sp. YC001",TRUE,50,46,49.9157436403789,113.44537815126
230,25,5.50900446637347,"Chlorella vulgaris",TRUE,50,29,47.2454977668133,72.6050420168067
230,26,5.50900446637347,"Chlorella sorokiniana",TRUE,50,30,47.2454977668133,75.6302521008403
229,27,5.50900446637347,"Tetraselmis suecica",TRUE,50,23,47.2454977668133,57.4789915966387
168,28,13.4234311696308,"Phaeocystis sp.",TRUE,50,14,43.2882844151846,36.3025210084034
164,29,33.0083008097399,"Pelagomonas sp.",TRUE,50,88,33.4958495951301,208.739495798319
164,30,33.0083008097399,"Spumella sp.",TRUE,50,87,33.4958495951301,207.226890756303
170,31,5.50900446637347,"Micromonas sp.",TRUE,50,20,47.2454977668133,48.4033613445378
204,32,12.6124637082775,"Haematococcus lacustris",TRUE,50,48,43.6937681458612,117.983193277311
235,33,0.424607707038035,"Chlorella sp. M2",TRUE,50,33,49.787696146481,83.1932773109244
235,34,0.424607707038035,"Chlorella sp. M6",TRUE,50,34,49.787696146481,84.7058823529412
236,35,0.168512719242249,"Scenedesmus sp. R3",TRUE,50,47,49.9157436403789,116.470588235294
228,36,5.50900446637347,"Chlamydomonas zebra",TRUE,50,56,47.2454977668133,136.134453781513
215,37,5.50900446637347,"Chlorococcum pamirum",TRUE,50,51,47.2454977668133,125.546218487395
232,38,5.50900446637347,"Coelastrella sp.",TRUE,50,42,47.2454977668133,102.857142857143
214,39,9.07369660419028,"Dunaliella salina",TRUE,50,49,45.4631516979049,119.495798319328
185,40,9.07369660419028,"Graesiella emersonii",TRUE,50,28,45.4631516979049,71.0924369747899
166,41,12.6124637082775,"Bumilleriopsis filiformis",TRUE,50,89,43.6937681458612,210.252100840336
216,42,9.07369660419028,"Carteria lunzensis",TRUE,50,53,45.4631516979049,130.084033613445
228,43,5.50900446637347,"Chlamydomonas hydra",TRUE,50,57,47.2454977668133,139.159663865546
231,44,5.50900446637347,"[Chlorella] fusca",TRUE,50,44,47.2454977668133,107.394957983193
217,45,9.07369660419028,"Neodesmus pupukensis",TRUE,50,40,45.4631516979049,98.3193277310924
217,46,9.07369660419028,"Enallax costatus",TRUE,50,39,45.4631516979049,95.2941176470588
232,47,5.50900446637347,"Coelastrella oocystiformis",TRUE,50,43,47.2454977668133,105.882352941176
186,48,9.07369660419028,"Valeriella excentrica",TRUE,50,36,45.4631516979049,87.7310924369748
186,49,9.07369660419028,"Spongiochloris spongiosa",TRUE,50,37,45.4631516979049,90.7563025210084
234,50,0.511691461277318,"Chlamydomonas sp. CRP7",TRUE,50,58,49.7441542693613,140.672268907563
235,51,0.424607707038035,"Chlorella sp. CB4",TRUE,50,32,49.787696146481,80.1680672268908
213,52,5.50900446637347,"Cymbella microcephala",TRUE,50,147,47.2454977668133,341.848739495798
227,53,5.50900446637347,"Ulnaria acus",TRUE,50,105,47.2454977668133,249.579831932773
225,54,5.50900446637347,"Fragilaria pinnata",TRUE,50,112,47.2454977668133,267.731092436975
227,55,5.50900446637347,"Ulnaria ulna",TRUE,50,106,47.2454977668133,252.605042016807
202,56,12.6124637082775,"Gomphonema clavatum",TRUE,50,145,43.6937681458612,337.310924369748
232,57,5.50900446637347,"Coelastrella terrestris",TRUE,50,41,47.2454977668133,99.8319327731092
205,58,9.07369660419028,"Isochrysis galbana",TRUE,50,15,45.4631516979049,37.8151260504202
165,59,9.07369660419028,"Heterosigma akashiwo",TRUE,50,92,45.4631516979049,216.302521008403
170,60,5.50900446637347,"Micromonas pusilla",TRUE,50,21,47.2454977668133,51.4285714285714
234,61,0.511691461277318,"Chlamydomonas sp.",TRUE,50,59,49.7441542693613,143.697478991597
161,62,28.2899446709569,"Platymonas",TRUE,50,17,35.8550276645215,42.3529411764706
168,63,13.4234311696308,"Syracosphaera",TRUE,50,13,43.2882844151846,31.7647058823529
160,64,28.2899446709569,"Diacronema lutheri",TRUE,50,11,35.8550276645215,27.2268907563025
168,65,13.4234311696308,"Prymnesium parvum",TRUE,50,12,43.2882844151846,28.7394957983193
184,66,12.6124637082775,"Hemiselmis sp.",TRUE,50,5,43.6937681458612,13.6134453781513
223,67,5.50900446637347,"Cylindrotheca sp.",TRUE,50,149,47.2454977668133,346.386554621849
229,68,5.50900446637347,"Tetraselmis sp.",TRUE,50,24,47.2454977668133,60.5042016806723
200,69,12.6124637082775,"Phaeodactylum tricornutum",TRUE,50,141,43.6937681458612,328.235294117647
165,70,9.07369660419028,"Chattonella marina var. antiqua",TRUE,50,93,45.4631516979049,219.327731092437
165,71,9.07369660419028,"Fibrocapsa japonica",TRUE,50,91,45.4631516979049,214.789915966387
222,72,5.50900446637347,"Alexandrium tamarense",TRUE,50,67,47.2454977668133,158.823529411765
163,73,21.5908249902037,"Levanderina fissa",TRUE,50,61,39.2045875048982,146.72268907563
221,74,5.50900446637347,"Heterocapsa triquetra",TRUE,50,85,47.2454977668133,202.689075630252
181,75,5.50900446637347,"Prorocentrum micans",TRUE,50,78,47.2454977668133,186.050420168067
181,76,5.50900446637347,"Prorocentrum minimum",TRUE,50,79,47.2454977668133,187.563025210084
181,77,5.50900446637347,"Prorocentrum triestinum",TRUE,50,77,47.2454977668133,184.53781512605
210,78,9.07369660419028,"Scrippsiella trochoidea",TRUE,50,82,45.4631516979049,193.613445378151
158,79,16.1843752478482,"Eutreptiella sp.",TRUE,50,7,41.9078123760759,18.1512605042017
167,80,28.2899446709569,"Bacillariophyta",TRUE,50,94,35.8550276645215,222.352941176471
224,81,5.50900446637347,"Nitzschia thermalis",TRUE,50,153,47.2454977668133,356.974789915966
199,82,5.50900446637347,"Amphora sp.",TRUE,50,139,47.2454977668133,323.697478991597
223,83,5.50900446637347,"Cylindrotheca closterium",TRUE,50,150,47.2454977668133,349.411764705882
226,84,5.50900446637347,"Synedra hyperborea",TRUE,50,109,47.2454977668133,258.655462184874
226,85,5.50900446637347,"Synedra minuscula",TRUE,50,110,47.2454977668133,263.193277310924
225,86,5.50900446637347,"Fragilaria sp.",TRUE,50,113,47.2454977668133,270.756302521008
192,87,5.50900446637347,"Chaetoceros sp.",TRUE,50,120,47.2454977668133,288.90756302521
228,88,5.50900446637347,"Chlamydomonas raudensis",TRUE,50,55,47.2454977668133,134.621848739496
195,89,9.07369660419028,"Synedropsis sp.",TRUE,50,108,45.4631516979049,257.142857142857
195,90,9.07369660419028,"Grammonema striatula",TRUE,50,107,45.4631516979049,255.63025210084
203,91,12.6124637082775,"Pseudopediastrum boryanum",TRUE,50,38,43.6937681458612,92.2689075630252
228,92,5.50900446637347,"Chlamydomonas reinhardtii",TRUE,50,54,47.2454977668133,131.596638655462
210,93,9.07369660419028,"Peridinium bipes",TRUE,50,83,45.4631516979049,198.151260504202
220,94,5.50900446637347,"Karenia mikimotoi",TRUE,50,72,47.2454977668133,173.949579831933
169,95,5.50900446637347,"Trentepohlia aurea",TRUE,50,18,47.2454977668133,43.8655462184874
169,96,5.50900446637347,"Trentepohlia odorata",TRUE,50,19,47.2454977668133,46.890756302521
205,97,9.07369660419028,"Chrysotila roscoffensis",TRUE,50,16,45.4631516979049,40.8403361344538
185,98,9.07369660419028,"Auxenochlorella pyrenoidosa",TRUE,50,27,45.4631516979049,68.0672268907563
179,99,5.50900446637347,"Amphidinium carterae",TRUE,50,63,47.2454977668133,149.747899159664
156,100,21.5908249902037,"Thermostichus lividus",TRUE,50,1,39.2045875048982,3.02521008403361
193,101,12.6124637082775,"Coscinodiscus granii",TRUE,50,115,43.6937681458612,275.294117647059
196,102,12.6124637082775,"Licmophora sp.",TRUE,50,102,43.6937681458612,242.016806722689
218,103,5.50900446637347,"Skeletonema costatum",TRUE,50,117,47.2454977668133,279.831932773109
212,104,9.07369660419028,"Tabularia affinis",TRUE,50,103,45.4631516979049,243.529411764706
222,105,5.50900446637347,"Alexandrium hiranoi",TRUE,50,68,47.2454977668133,161.848739495798
194,106,5.50900446637347,"Euglena gracilis",TRUE,50,9,47.2454977668133,22.6890756302521
184,107,12.6124637082775,"Cryptomonas sp.",TRUE,50,6,43.6937681458612,16.6386554621849
159,108,21.5908249902037,"Rhodomonas sp.",TRUE,50,4,39.2045875048982,10.5882352941176
163,109,21.5908249902037,"Symbiodinium sp.",TRUE,50,60,39.2045875048982,145.210084033613
199,110,5.50900446637347,"Amphora coffeiformis",TRUE,50,140,47.2454977668133,325.210084033613
199,111,5.50900446637347,"Amphora laevissima",TRUE,50,138,47.2454977668133,320.672268907563
199,112,5.50900446637347,"Amphora ovalis",TRUE,50,137,47.2454977668133,319.159663865546
206,113,5.50900446637347,"Cocconeis placentula",TRUE,50,135,47.2454977668133,314.621848739496
206,114,5.50900446637347,"Cocconeis scutellum",TRUE,50,136,47.2454977668133,317.647058823529
175,115,21.5908249902037,"Cymatosira belgica",TRUE,50,95,39.2045875048982,223.865546218487
213,116,5.50900446637347,"Cymbella pusilla",TRUE,50,148,47.2454977668133,344.873949579832
200,117,12.6124637082775,"Fallacia pygmaea",TRUE,50,142,43.6937681458612,329.747899159664
211,118,5.50900446637347,"Navicula cryptocephala",TRUE,50,143,47.2454977668133,332.773109243697
211,119,5.50900446637347,"Navicula viridula",TRUE,50,144,47.2454977668133,335.798319327731
224,120,5.50900446637347,"Nitzschia commutata",TRUE,50,154,47.2454977668133,358.487394957983
224,121,5.50900446637347,"Nitzschia pellucida",TRUE,50,152,47.2454977668133,353.949579831933
173,122,15.1862614492595,"Petrodictyon gemma",TRUE,50,133,42.4068692753703,310.084033613445
176,123,9.07369660419028,"Scherffelia dubia",TRUE,50,22,45.4631516979049,54.453781512605
214,124,9.07369660419028,"Spermatozopsis similis",TRUE,50,50,45.4631516979049,122.521008403361
198,125,12.6124637082775,"Achnanthidium minutissimum",TRUE,50,134,43.6937681458612,311.596638655462
213,126,5.50900446637347,"Cymbella affiniformis",TRUE,50,146,47.2454977668133,338.823529411765
224,127,5.50900446637347,"Nitzschia palea",TRUE,50,151,47.2454977668133,350.924369747899
208,128,9.07369660419028,"Gymnodinium impudicum",TRUE,50,69,45.4631516979049,164.873949579832
185,129,9.07369660419028,"Pseudochlorella pringsheimii",TRUE,50,26,45.4631516979049,65.0420168067227
188,130,12.6124637082775,"Arthrospira sp.",TRUE,50,3,43.6937681458612,9.07563025210084
194,131,5.50900446637347,"Euglena hiemalis",TRUE,50,10,47.2454977668133,25.7142857142857
194,132,5.50900446637347,"Euglena longa",TRUE,50,8,47.2454977668133,19.6638655462185
236,133,0.168512719242249,"Scenedesmus sp.",TRUE,50,45,49.9157436403789,108.90756302521
222,134,5.50900446637347,"Alexandrium minutum",TRUE,50,66,47.2454977668133,155.798319327731
225,135,5.50900446637347,"Fragilaria radians",TRUE,50,111,47.2454977668133,264.705882352941
182,136,12.6124637082775,"Pfiesteria shumwayae",TRUE,50,81,43.6937681458612,190.588235294118
235,137,0.424607707038035,"Chlorella sp.",TRUE,50,31,49.787696146481,78.655462184874
183,138,9.07369660419028,"Pyrodinium bahamense",TRUE,50,65,45.4631516979049,154.285714285714
178,139,21.5908249902037,"Stichococcus bacillaris",TRUE,50,25,39.2045875048982,62.0168067226891
215,140,5.50900446637347,"Chlorococcum humicola",TRUE,50,52,47.2454977668133,128.571428571429
177,141,21.5908249902037,"Stigeoclonium tenue",TRUE,50,35,39.2045875048982,86.218487394958
166,142,12.6124637082775,"Botrydiopsis sp.",TRUE,50,90,43.6937681458612,213.27731092437
208,143,9.07369660419028,"Akashiwo sanguinea",TRUE,50,70,45.4631516979049,167.899159663866
179,144,5.50900446637347,"Amphidinium gibbosum",TRUE,50,64,47.2454977668133,152.773109243697
179,145,5.50900446637347,"Amphidinium massartii",TRUE,50,62,47.2454977668133,148.235294117647
209,146,9.07369660419028,"Cachonina",TRUE,50,84,45.4631516979049,199.663865546218
221,147,5.50900446637347,"Heterocapsa sp.",TRUE,50,86,47.2454977668133,205.714285714286
182,148,12.6124637082775,"Coolia monotis",TRUE,50,80,43.6937681458612,189.075630252101
220,149,5.50900446637347,"Karenia brevis",TRUE,50,73,47.2454977668133,176.974789915966
207,150,9.07369660419028,"Karlodinium veneficum",TRUE,50,71,45.4631516979049,170.924369747899
181,151,5.50900446637347,"Prorocentrum donghaiense",TRUE,50,76,47.2454977668133,181.512605042017
181,152,5.50900446637347,"Prorocentrum hoffmannianum",TRUE,50,75,47.2454977668133,180
181,153,5.50900446637347,"Prorocentrum rhathymum",TRUE,50,74,47.2454977668133,178.487394957983
227,154,5.50900446637347,"Ulnaria danica",TRUE,50,104,47.2454977668133,246.554621848739
155,155,0,"cellular organisms",FALSE,0,13.6183407738095,0,33.2773109243697
155,156,28.4091750097963,"Cyanophyceae",FALSE,28.4091750097963,1.75,14.2045875048982,4.53781512605042
155,157,6.48773969082659,"Eukaryota",FALSE,6.48773969082659,25.486681547619,3.24386984541329,63.5294117647059
157,158,27.3278850613252,"Euglenophyceae",FALSE,33.8156247521518,8,20.1516822214892,21.1764705882353
157,159,21.9214353189698,"Cryptophyceae",FALSE,28.4091750097963,4.75,17.4484573503115,12.1008403361345
157,160,15.2223156382165,"Haptophyta",FALSE,21.7100553290431,12.3125,14.0988975099348,30.2521008403361
157,161,15.2223156382165,"Chlorophyta",FALSE,21.7100553290431,21.3439236111111,14.0988975099348,52.9411764705882
157,162,8.65031958776878,"Sar",FALSE,15.1380592785954,81.0269841269841,10.812899484711,192.100840336134
162,163,13.271115731201,"Dinophyceae",FALSE,28.4091750097963,68.4553571428571,21.7736171441959,163.361344537815
162,164,1.85363991166474,"Ochrophyta",FALSE,16.9916991902601,93.5986111111111,16.0648792344277,220.840336134454
164,165,23.9346042055496,"Chattonellaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,92,28.9590012930349,217.81512605042
164,166,20.3958371014624,"Mischococcales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,89.5,27.1896177409913,211.764705882353
164,167,4.71835613878297,"Bacillariophyta",FALSE,21.7100553290431,111.493055555556,19.3508772596516,266.218487394958
160,168,14.8665135013261,"Prymnesiophyceae",FALSE,36.5765688303692,13.625,29.1433120797061,34.7899159663866
161,169,22.7809402045835,"Trentepohlia",FALSE,44.4909955336265,18.5,33.1005254313348,45.3781512605042
161,170,22.7809402045835,"Micromonas",FALSE,44.4909955336265,20.5,33.1005254313348,49.9159663865546
161,171,5.46335973964344,"core chlorophytes",FALSE,27.1734150686865,29.3756944444444,24.4417351988648,74.1176470588235
167,172,12.1055694231088,"Fragilariophycidae",FALSE,33.8156247521518,106.0625,27.7628400405974,254.117647058824
167,173,13.1036832216975,"Bacillariophycidae",FALSE,34.8137385507405,140.902777777778,28.2618969398918,326.72268907563
167,174,6.69911968075327,"Coscinodiscophyceae",FALSE,28.4091750097963,119.333333333333,25.0596151694197,287.394957983193
167,175,6.69911968075327,"Mediophyceae",FALSE,28.4091750097963,97.1666666666667,25.0596151694197,229.915966386555
171,176,13.7528883271232,"Chlorodendraceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,22.75,34.0498592322481,55.9663865546218
171,177,1.23575994110983,"Chlorophyceae",FALSE,28.4091750097963,38.9395833333333,27.7912950392414,93.781512605042
171,178,1.23575994110983,"Trebouxiophyceae",FALSE,28.4091750097963,26.4375,27.7912950392414,66.5546218487395
163,179,16.0818205238302,"Amphidinium",FALSE,44.4909955336265,63,36.4500852717114,151.260504201681
163,180,8.97836128192615,"Gymnodiniales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,70.625,32.8983556507594,169.411764705882
163,181,16.0818205238302,"Prorocentrum",FALSE,44.4909955336265,76.5,36.4500852717114,183.025210084034
163,182,8.97836128192615,"Peridiniales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,82.0625,32.8983556507594,195.126050420168
163,183,12.5171283860134,"Pyrocystaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,66,34.667739202803,157.310924369748
159,184,8.97836128192615,"Cryptomonadales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,5.5,32.8983556507594,15.1260504201681
178,185,12.5171283860134,"Chlorellaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,27.875,34.667739202803,69.5798319327731
177,186,12.5171283860134,"Protosiphonaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,36.5,34.667739202803,89.2436974789916
177,187,7.87904983431387,"CS clade",FALSE,36.2882248441102,45.31875,32.3486999269533,111.932773109244
156,188,8.97836128192615,"Oscillatoriales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,2.5,32.8983556507594,7.56302521008403
175,189,12.5171283860134,"Lithodesmiaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,96.75,34.667739202803,226.890756302521
175,190,5.40644974235549,"Biddulphiophycidae",FALSE,33.8156247521518,99.75,31.1123998809741,235.966386554622
174,191,8.97836128192615,"Thalassiosirales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,117.5,32.8983556507594,281.344537815126
174,192,16.0818205238302,"Chaetoceros",FALSE,44.4909955336265,126,36.4500852717114,299.495798319328
174,193,8.97836128192615,"Coscinodiscales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,114.5,32.8983556507594,273.781512605042
158,194,10.6753707814747,"Euglena",FALSE,44.4909955336265,9,39.1533101428892,24.2016806722689
172,195,7.1106786436579,"Fragilariaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,109.125,37.3709640739808,260.168067226891
172,196,3.57191153957067,"Licmophorales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,103,35.6015805219372,245.042016806723
190,197,10.6753707814747,"Odontella",FALSE,44.4909955336265,100.5,39.1533101428892,238.991596638655
173,198,2.57379774098196,"Cocconeidales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,134.75,36.1006374212315,313.109243697479
173,199,9.677256982886,"Amphora",FALSE,44.4909955336265,138.5,39.6523670421835,322.18487394958
173,200,2.57379774098196,"Naviculales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,142.166666666667,36.1006374212315,331.260504201681
173,201,6.11256484506919,"Bacillariaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,151,37.8700209732751,352.436974789916
173,202,2.57379774098196,"Cymbellales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,146,36.1006374212315,340.336134453781
187,203,1.09931144761228,"Sphaeropleales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,39.75,36.8378805679164,96.8067226890756
187,204,1.09931144761228,"Chlamydomonadales",FALSE,37.3875362917225,50.8875,36.8378805679164,124.033613445378
168,205,4.34973456544055,"Isochrysidaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,15.5,38.7514361130894,39.327731092437
198,206,7.10345924190403,"Cocconeis",FALSE,44.4909955336265,135.5,40.9392659126745,316.134453781513
180,207,3.53876710408723,"Kareniaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,71.75,39.1569198437661,172.436974789916
180,208,3.53876710408723,"Gymnodiniaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,69.5,39.1569198437661,166.386554621849
182,209,3.53876710408723,"Heterocapsaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,84.75,39.1569198437661,201.176470588235
182,210,3.53876710408723,"Peridiniaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,82.5,39.1569198437661,196.638655462185
200,211,7.10345924190403,"Navicula",FALSE,44.4909955336265,143.5,40.9392659126745,334.285714285714
196,212,3.53876710408723,"Ulnariaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,104,39.1569198437661,248.067226890756
202,213,7.10345924190403,"Cymbella",FALSE,44.4909955336265,147,40.9392659126745,343.361344537815
204,214,3.53876710408723,"Dunaliellaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,49.5,39.1569198437661,121.008403361345
204,215,7.10345924190403,"Chlorococcum",FALSE,44.4909955336265,51.5,40.9392659126745,127.058823529412
204,216,3.53876710408723,"Chlamydomonadaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,54.55,39.1569198437661,133.109243697479
203,217,3.53876710408723,"Scenedesmaceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,41.5,39.1569198437661,101.344537815126
191,218,7.10345924190403,"Skeletonema",FALSE,44.4909955336265,116.5,40.9392659126745,278.319327731092
191,219,3.53876710408723,"Thalassiosiraceae",FALSE,40.9263033958097,118.5,39.1569198437661,284.36974789916
207,220,3.56469213781681,"Karenia",FALSE,44.4909955336265,72.5,42.7086494647181,175.46218487395
209,221,3.56469213781681,"Heterocapsa",FALSE,44.4909955336265,85.5,42.7086494647181,204.201680672269
183,222,3.56469213781681,"Alexandrium",FALSE,44.4909955336265,67,42.7086494647181,160.336134453782
201,223,3.56469213781681,"Cylindrotheca",FALSE,44.4909955336265,149.5,42.7086494647181,347.899159663866
201,224,3.56469213781681,"Nitzschia",FALSE,44.4909955336265,152.5,42.7086494647181,355.46218487395
195,225,3.56469213781681,"Fragilaria",FALSE,44.4909955336265,112,42.7086494647181,269.243697478992
195,226,3.56469213781681,"Synedra",FALSE,44.4909955336265,109.5,42.7086494647181,261.680672268908
212,227,3.56469213781681,"Ulnaria",FALSE,44.4909955336265,105,42.7086494647181,251.09243697479
216,228,3.56469213781681,"Chlamydomonas",FALSE,44.4909955336265,56.1,42.7086494647181,137.647058823529
176,229,3.56469213781681,"Tetraselmis",FALSE,44.4909955336265,23.5,42.7086494647181,58.9915966386555
185,230,3.56469213781681,"Chlorella",FALSE,44.4909955336265,30.5,42.7086494647181,77.1428571428571
217,231,3.56469213781681,"Scenedesmus",FALSE,44.4909955336265,45,42.7086494647181,110.420168067227
217,232,3.56469213781681,"Coelastrella",FALSE,44.4909955336265,42,42.7086494647181,104.36974789916
189,233,3.56469213781681,"Lithodesmium",FALSE,44.4909955336265,97.5,42.7086494647181,231.428571428571
228,234,4.99731300509615,"unclassified Chlamydomonas",FALSE,49.4883085387227,58.5,46.9896520361746,142.18487394958
230,235,5.08439675933544,"unclassified Chlorella",FALSE,49.575392292962,32.5,47.0331939132942,81.6806722689076
231,236,5.34049174713122,"unclassified Scenedesmus",FALSE,49.8314872807578,46,47.1612414071921,114.957983193277

Note: I am acutely aware that the community does not appreciate such messages or requests. If this violates the rule, I request the moderators to remove this post. I've asked this as an absolute last resort.

I don't know of any existing package that produces trees like this, so I think you are much better off figuring out how to get the R version to look nicer.

^^ What Alan said. The only thing I know which produces these kind of circular trees is the builtin pgf/tikz support for trees which has a syntax which would, in my opinion, make this a nightmare and certainly be difficult to parse. Unless there's something for, say, Metapost, I'd say you want an external programme. I know nothing about R, but I wouldn't look to do think in LaTeX unless you're up for writing the package ;).

@cfr : "...unless you're up for writing the package". Sounds like future Miloop's problem!

@Miloop Be careful what you ask for - you might end up making it ;).

It seems like your data has already all the needed values to drawing this directly – and them some I don't know what they mean.
I'm using the csvsimple-l3 package for accessing the CSV file. The package doesn't support " from the get-go so I've removed them from all values and the header. It does support TeX grouping via braces {} and also contains a section about how to use ", though I didn't bother to read it.

With the \csvreader{<file>}{<asgmts>}{<body>} command we can loop through all rows. Its second argument is used to assign a macro name to each column name.
I'm using the ext.misc libary from my tikz-ext package for the /utils/if={<cond>}{<true>}{<false>} key that applies different key-value pairs depending on the outcome of <cond>. This is used to rotate and place the text correctly depending on the \angle value.
Since we know the radius (that's the x column apparently) and the angle for each point I store them away for drawing the connections in the do style.
(We could use the calc library to evaluate the needed radius and angles but in this case I rather waste memory instead of time – the compiler's and mine.)

This diagram looks a little bit different than your image but some nodes in your image are missing in the data (e.g. the very first “Lamprocystis”) and maybe the three remaining values I didn't consider have something to do with that.
If you want the parent nodes to be circles (right now they are coordinates) a little bit of work is necessary so that the arcs aren't drawn on top of it.
If you need some of the connections to be differently styled depending on the parent or child node, some exta work is necessary as well but it is certainly doable.
Code
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
parent,node,branch.length,label,isTip,x,y,branch,angle
192,1,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros affinis,TRUE,50,131,47.2454977668133,307.058823529412
193,2,12.6124637082775,Actinocyclus sp. (in: diatoms),TRUE,50,114,43.6937681458612,272.268907563025
192,3,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros hirtisetus,TRUE,50,132,47.2454977668133,308.571428571429
192,4,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros curvisetus,TRUE,50,130,47.2454977668133,305.546218487395
192,5,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros debilis,TRUE,50,129,47.2454977668133,304.033613445378
192,6,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros diadema,TRUE,50,128,47.2454977668133,302.521008403361
192,7,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros didymus,TRUE,50,127,47.2454977668133,301.008403361345
192,8,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros eibenii,TRUE,50,126,47.2454977668133,297.983193277311
192,9,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros lorenzianus,TRUE,50,125,47.2454977668133,296.470588235294
192,10,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros protuberans,TRUE,50,124,47.2454977668133,294.957983193277
192,11,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros pseudocurvisetus,TRUE,50,123,47.2454977668133,293.445378151261
192,12,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros radicans,TRUE,50,122,47.2454977668133,291.932773109244
192,13,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros seiracanthus,TRUE,50,121,47.2454977668133,290.420168067227
219,14,9.07369660419028,Detonula pumila,TRUE,50,118,45.4631516979049,282.857142857143
189,15,9.07369660419028,Ditylum brightwellii,TRUE,50,96,45.4631516979049,225.378151260504
190,16,16.1843752478482,Hemiaulus hauckii,TRUE,50,99,41.9078123760759,234.453781512605
233,17,5.50900446637347,Lithodesmium undulatum,TRUE,50,97,47.2454977668133,228.403361344538
233,18,5.50900446637347,Lithodesmium variabile,TRUE,50,98,47.2454977668133,232.941176470588
197,19,5.50900446637347,Odontella aurita,TRUE,50,100,47.2454977668133,237.478991596639
197,20,5.50900446637347,Odontella longicruris,TRUE,50,101,47.2454977668133,240.504201680672
218,21,5.50900446637347,Skeletonema sp.,TRUE,50,116,47.2454977668133,276.806722689076
219,22,9.07369660419028,Thalassiosira sp.,TRUE,50,119,45.4631516979049,285.882352941176
188,23,12.6124637082775,Limnospira fusiformis,TRUE,50,2,43.6937681458612,6.05042016806723
236,24,0.168512719242249,Scenedesmus sp. YC001,TRUE,50,46,49.9157436403789,113.44537815126
230,25,5.50900446637347,Chlorella vulgaris,TRUE,50,29,47.2454977668133,72.6050420168067
230,26,5.50900446637347,Chlorella sorokiniana,TRUE,50,30,47.2454977668133,75.6302521008403
229,27,5.50900446637347,Tetraselmis suecica,TRUE,50,23,47.2454977668133,57.4789915966387
168,28,13.4234311696308,Phaeocystis sp.,TRUE,50,14,43.2882844151846,36.3025210084034
164,29,33.0083008097399,Pelagomonas sp.,TRUE,50,88,33.4958495951301,208.739495798319
164,30,33.0083008097399,Spumella sp.,TRUE,50,87,33.4958495951301,207.226890756303
170,31,5.50900446637347,Micromonas sp.,TRUE,50,20,47.2454977668133,48.4033613445378
204,32,12.6124637082775,Haematococcus lacustris,TRUE,50,48,43.6937681458612,117.983193277311
235,33,0.424607707038035,Chlorella sp. M2,TRUE,50,33,49.787696146481,83.1932773109244
235,34,0.424607707038035,Chlorella sp. M6,TRUE,50,34,49.787696146481,84.7058823529412
236,35,0.168512719242249,Scenedesmus sp. R3,TRUE,50,47,49.9157436403789,116.470588235294
228,36,5.50900446637347,Chlamydomonas zebra,TRUE,50,56,47.2454977668133,136.134453781513
215,37,5.50900446637347,Chlorococcum pamirum,TRUE,50,51,47.2454977668133,125.546218487395
232,38,5.50900446637347,Coelastrella sp.,TRUE,50,42,47.2454977668133,102.857142857143
214,39,9.07369660419028,Dunaliella salina,TRUE,50,49,45.4631516979049,119.495798319328
185,40,9.07369660419028,Graesiella emersonii,TRUE,50,28,45.4631516979049,71.0924369747899
166,41,12.6124637082775,Bumilleriopsis filiformis,TRUE,50,89,43.6937681458612,210.252100840336
216,42,9.07369660419028,Carteria lunzensis,TRUE,50,53,45.4631516979049,130.084033613445
228,43,5.50900446637347,Chlamydomonas hydra,TRUE,50,57,47.2454977668133,139.159663865546
231,44,5.50900446637347,[Chlorella] fusca,TRUE,50,44,47.2454977668133,107.394957983193
217,45,9.07369660419028,Neodesmus pupukensis,TRUE,50,40,45.4631516979049,98.3193277310924
217,46,9.07369660419028,Enallax costatus,TRUE,50,39,45.4631516979049,95.2941176470588
232,47,5.50900446637347,Coelastrella oocystiformis,TRUE,50,43,47.2454977668133,105.882352941176
186,48,9.07369660419028,Valeriella excentrica,TRUE,50,36,45.4631516979049,87.7310924369748
186,49,9.07369660419028,Spongiochloris spongiosa,TRUE,50,37,45.4631516979049,90.7563025210084
234,50,0.511691461277318,Chlamydomonas sp. CRP7,TRUE,50,58,49.7441542693613,140.672268907563
235,51,0.424607707038035,Chlorella sp. CB4,TRUE,50,32,49.787696146481,80.1680672268908
213,52,5.50900446637347,Cymbella microcephala,TRUE,50,147,47.2454977668133,341.848739495798
227,53,5.50900446637347,Ulnaria acus,TRUE,50,105,47.2454977668133,249.579831932773
225,54,5.50900446637347,Fragilaria pinnata,TRUE,50,112,47.2454977668133,267.731092436975
227,55,5.50900446637347,Ulnaria ulna,TRUE,50,106,47.2454977668133,252.605042016807
202,56,12.6124637082775,Gomphonema clavatum,TRUE,50,145,43.6937681458612,337.310924369748
232,57,5.50900446637347,Coelastrella terrestris,TRUE,50,41,47.2454977668133,99.8319327731092
205,58,9.07369660419028,Isochrysis galbana,TRUE,50,15,45.4631516979049,37.8151260504202
165,59,9.07369660419028,Heterosigma akashiwo,TRUE,50,92,45.4631516979049,216.302521008403
170,60,5.50900446637347,Micromonas pusilla,TRUE,50,21,47.2454977668133,51.4285714285714
234,61,0.511691461277318,Chlamydomonas sp.,TRUE,50,59,49.7441542693613,143.697478991597
161,62,28.2899446709569,Platymonas,TRUE,50,17,35.8550276645215,42.3529411764706
168,63,13.4234311696308,Syracosphaera,TRUE,50,13,43.2882844151846,31.7647058823529
160,64,28.2899446709569,Diacronema lutheri,TRUE,50,11,35.8550276645215,27.2268907563025
168,65,13.4234311696308,Prymnesium parvum,TRUE,50,12,43.2882844151846,28.7394957983193
184,66,12.6124637082775,Hemiselmis sp.,TRUE,50,5,43.6937681458612,13.6134453781513
223,67,5.50900446637347,Cylindrotheca sp.,TRUE,50,149,47.2454977668133,346.386554621849
229,68,5.50900446637347,Tetraselmis sp.,TRUE,50,24,47.2454977668133,60.5042016806723
200,69,12.6124637082775,Phaeodactylum tricornutum,TRUE,50,141,43.6937681458612,328.235294117647
165,70,9.07369660419028,Chattonella marina var. antiqua,TRUE,50,93,45.4631516979049,219.327731092437
165,71,9.07369660419028,Fibrocapsa japonica,TRUE,50,91,45.4631516979049,214.789915966387
222,72,5.50900446637347,Alexandrium tamarense,TRUE,50,67,47.2454977668133,158.823529411765
163,73,21.5908249902037,Levanderina fissa,TRUE,50,61,39.2045875048982,146.72268907563
221,74,5.50900446637347,Heterocapsa triquetra,TRUE,50,85,47.2454977668133,202.689075630252
181,75,5.50900446637347,Prorocentrum micans,TRUE,50,78,47.2454977668133,186.050420168067
181,76,5.50900446637347,Prorocentrum minimum,TRUE,50,79,47.2454977668133,187.563025210084
181,77,5.50900446637347,Prorocentrum triestinum,TRUE,50,77,47.2454977668133,184.53781512605
210,78,9.07369660419028,Scrippsiella trochoidea,TRUE,50,82,45.4631516979049,193.613445378151
158,79,16.1843752478482,Eutreptiella sp.,TRUE,50,7,41.9078123760759,18.1512605042017
167,80,28.2899446709569,Bacillariophyta,TRUE,50,94,35.8550276645215,222.352941176471
224,81,5.50900446637347,Nitzschia thermalis,TRUE,50,153,47.2454977668133,356.974789915966
199,82,5.50900446637347,Amphora sp.,TRUE,50,139,47.2454977668133,323.697478991597
223,83,5.50900446637347,Cylindrotheca closterium,TRUE,50,150,47.2454977668133,349.411764705882
226,84,5.50900446637347,Synedra hyperborea,TRUE,50,109,47.2454977668133,258.655462184874
226,85,5.50900446637347,Synedra minuscula,TRUE,50,110,47.2454977668133,263.193277310924
225,86,5.50900446637347,Fragilaria sp.,TRUE,50,113,47.2454977668133,270.756302521008
192,87,5.50900446637347,Chaetoceros sp.,TRUE,50,120,47.2454977668133,288.90756302521
228,88,5.50900446637347,Chlamydomonas raudensis,TRUE,50,55,47.2454977668133,134.621848739496
195,89,9.07369660419028,Synedropsis sp.,TRUE,50,108,45.4631516979049,257.142857142857
195,90,9.07369660419028,Grammonema striatula,TRUE,50,107,45.4631516979049,255.63025210084
203,91,12.6124637082775,Pseudopediastrum boryanum,TRUE,50,38,43.6937681458612,92.2689075630252
228,92,5.50900446637347,Chlamydomonas reinhardtii,TRUE,50,54,47.2454977668133,131.596638655462
210,93,9.07369660419028,Peridinium bipes,TRUE,50,83,45.4631516979049,198.151260504202
220,94,5.50900446637347,Karenia mikimotoi,TRUE,50,72,47.2454977668133,173.949579831933
169,95,5.50900446637347,Trentepohlia aurea,TRUE,50,18,47.2454977668133,43.8655462184874
169,96,5.50900446637347,Trentepohlia odorata,TRUE,50,19,47.2454977668133,46.890756302521
205,97,9.07369660419028,Chrysotila roscoffensis,TRUE,50,16,45.4631516979049,40.8403361344538
185,98,9.07369660419028,Auxenochlorella pyrenoidosa,TRUE,50,27,45.4631516979049,68.0672268907563
179,99,5.50900446637347,Amphidinium carterae,TRUE,50,63,47.2454977668133,149.747899159664
156,100,21.5908249902037,Thermostichus lividus,TRUE,50,1,39.2045875048982,3.02521008403361
193,101,12.6124637082775,Coscinodiscus granii,TRUE,50,115,43.6937681458612,275.294117647059
196,102,12.6124637082775,Licmophora sp.,TRUE,50,102,43.6937681458612,242.016806722689
218,103,5.50900446637347,Skeletonema costatum,TRUE,50,117,47.2454977668133,279.831932773109
212,104,9.07369660419028,Tabularia affinis,TRUE,50,103,45.4631516979049,243.529411764706
222,105,5.50900446637347,Alexandrium hiranoi,TRUE,50,68,47.2454977668133,161.848739495798
194,106,5.50900446637347,Euglena gracilis,TRUE,50,9,47.2454977668133,22.6890756302521
184,107,12.6124637082775,Cryptomonas sp.,TRUE,50,6,43.6937681458612,16.6386554621849
159,108,21.5908249902037,Rhodomonas sp.,TRUE,50,4,39.2045875048982,10.5882352941176
163,109,21.5908249902037,Symbiodinium sp.,TRUE,50,60,39.2045875048982,145.210084033613
199,110,5.50900446637347,Amphora coffeiformis,TRUE,50,140,47.2454977668133,325.210084033613
199,111,5.50900446637347,Amphora laevissima,TRUE,50,138,47.2454977668133,320.672268907563
199,112,5.50900446637347,Amphora ovalis,TRUE,50,137,47.2454977668133,319.159663865546
206,113,5.50900446637347,Cocconeis placentula,TRUE,50,135,47.2454977668133,314.621848739496
206,114,5.50900446637347,Cocconeis scutellum,TRUE,50,136,47.2454977668133,317.647058823529
175,115,21.5908249902037,Cymatosira belgica,TRUE,50,95,39.2045875048982,223.865546218487
213,116,5.50900446637347,Cymbella pusilla,TRUE,50,148,47.2454977668133,344.873949579832
200,117,12.6124637082775,Fallacia pygmaea,TRUE,50,142,43.6937681458612,329.747899159664
211,118,5.50900446637347,Navicula cryptocephala,TRUE,50,143,47.2454977668133,332.773109243697
211,119,5.50900446637347,Navicula viridula,TRUE,50,144,47.2454977668133,335.798319327731
224,120,5.50900446637347,Nitzschia commutata,TRUE,50,154,47.2454977668133,358.487394957983
224,121,5.50900446637347,Nitzschia pellucida,TRUE,50,152,47.2454977668133,353.949579831933
173,122,15.1862614492595,Petrodictyon gemma,TRUE,50,133,42.4068692753703,310.084033613445
176,123,9.07369660419028,Scherffelia dubia,TRUE,50,22,45.4631516979049,54.453781512605
214,124,9.07369660419028,Spermatozopsis similis,TRUE,50,50,45.4631516979049,122.521008403361
198,125,12.6124637082775,Achnanthidium minutissimum,TRUE,50,134,43.6937681458612,311.596638655462
213,126,5.50900446637347,Cymbella affiniformis,TRUE,50,146,47.2454977668133,338.823529411765
224,127,5.50900446637347,Nitzschia palea,TRUE,50,151,47.2454977668133,350.924369747899
208,128,9.07369660419028,Gymnodinium impudicum,TRUE,50,69,45.4631516979049,164.873949579832
185,129,9.07369660419028,Pseudochlorella pringsheimii,TRUE,50,26,45.4631516979049,65.0420168067227
188,130,12.6124637082775,Arthrospira sp.,TRUE,50,3,43.6937681458612,9.07563025210084
194,131,5.50900446637347,Euglena hiemalis,TRUE,50,10,47.2454977668133,25.7142857142857
194,132,5.50900446637347,Euglena longa,TRUE,50,8,47.2454977668133,19.6638655462185
236,133,0.168512719242249,Scenedesmus sp.,TRUE,50,45,49.9157436403789,108.90756302521
222,134,5.50900446637347,Alexandrium minutum,TRUE,50,66,47.2454977668133,155.798319327731
225,135,5.50900446637347,Fragilaria radians,TRUE,50,111,47.2454977668133,264.705882352941
182,136,12.6124637082775,Pfiesteria shumwayae,TRUE,50,81,43.6937681458612,190.588235294118
235,137,0.424607707038035,Chlorella sp.,TRUE,50,31,49.787696146481,78.655462184874
183,138,9.07369660419028,Pyrodinium bahamense,TRUE,50,65,45.4631516979049,154.285714285714
178,139,21.5908249902037,Stichococcus bacillaris,TRUE,50,25,39.2045875048982,62.0168067226891
215,140,5.50900446637347,Chlorococcum humicola,TRUE,50,52,47.2454977668133,128.571428571429
177,141,21.5908249902037,Stigeoclonium tenue,TRUE,50,35,39.2045875048982,86.218487394958
166,142,12.6124637082775,Botrydiopsis sp.,TRUE,50,90,43.6937681458612,213.27731092437
208,143,9.07369660419028,Akashiwo sanguinea,TRUE,50,70,45.4631516979049,167.899159663866
179,144,5.50900446637347,Amphidinium gibbosum,TRUE,50,64,47.2454977668133,152.773109243697
179,145,5.50900446637347,Amphidinium massartii,TRUE,50,62,47.2454977668133,148.235294117647
209,146,9.07369660419028,Cachonina,TRUE,50,84,45.4631516979049,199.663865546218
221,147,5.50900446637347,Heterocapsa sp.,TRUE,50,86,47.2454977668133,205.714285714286
182,148,12.6124637082775,Coolia monotis,TRUE,50,80,43.6937681458612,189.075630252101
220,149,5.50900446637347,Karenia brevis,TRUE,50,73,47.2454977668133,176.974789915966
207,150,9.07369660419028,Karlodinium veneficum,TRUE,50,71,45.4631516979049,170.924369747899
181,151,5.50900446637347,Prorocentrum donghaiense,TRUE,50,76,47.2454977668133,181.512605042017
181,152,5.50900446637347,Prorocentrum hoffmannianum,TRUE,50,75,47.2454977668133,180
181,153,5.50900446637347,Prorocentrum rhathymum,TRUE,50,74,47.2454977668133,178.487394957983
227,154,5.50900446637347,Ulnaria danica,TRUE,50,104,47.2454977668133,246.554621848739
155,155,0,cellular organisms,FALSE,0,13.6183407738095,0,33.2773109243697
155,156,28.4091750097963,Cyanophyceae,FALSE,28.4091750097963,1.75,14.2045875048982,4.53781512605042
155,157,6.48773969082659,Eukaryota,FALSE,6.48773969082659,25.486681547619,3.24386984541329,63.5294117647059
157,158,27.3278850613252,Euglenophyceae,FALSE,33.8156247521518,8,20.1516822214892,21.1764705882353
157,159,21.9214353189698,Cryptophyceae,FALSE,28.4091750097963,4.75,17.4484573503115,12.1008403361345
157,160,15.2223156382165,Haptophyta,FALSE,21.7100553290431,12.3125,14.0988975099348,30.2521008403361
157,161,15.2223156382165,Chlorophyta,FALSE,21.7100553290431,21.3439236111111,14.0988975099348,52.9411764705882
157,162,8.65031958776878,Sar,FALSE,15.1380592785954,81.0269841269841,10.812899484711,192.100840336134
162,163,13.271115731201,Dinophyceae,FALSE,28.4091750097963,68.4553571428571,21.7736171441959,163.361344537815
162,164,1.85363991166474,Ochrophyta,FALSE,16.9916991902601,93.5986111111111,16.0648792344277,220.840336134454
164,165,23.9346042055496,Chattonellaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,92,28.9590012930349,217.81512605042
164,166,20.3958371014624,Mischococcales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,89.5,27.1896177409913,211.764705882353
164,167,4.71835613878297,Bacillariophyta,FALSE,21.7100553290431,111.493055555556,19.3508772596516,266.218487394958
160,168,14.8665135013261,Prymnesiophyceae,FALSE,36.5765688303692,13.625,29.1433120797061,34.7899159663866
161,169,22.7809402045835,Trentepohlia,FALSE,44.4909955336265,18.5,33.1005254313348,45.3781512605042
161,170,22.7809402045835,Micromonas,FALSE,44.4909955336265,20.5,33.1005254313348,49.9159663865546
161,171,5.46335973964344,core chlorophytes,FALSE,27.1734150686865,29.3756944444444,24.4417351988648,74.1176470588235
167,172,12.1055694231088,Fragilariophycidae,FALSE,33.8156247521518,106.0625,27.7628400405974,254.117647058824
167,173,13.1036832216975,Bacillariophycidae,FALSE,34.8137385507405,140.902777777778,28.2618969398918,326.72268907563
167,174,6.69911968075327,Coscinodiscophyceae,FALSE,28.4091750097963,119.333333333333,25.0596151694197,287.394957983193
167,175,6.69911968075327,Mediophyceae,FALSE,28.4091750097963,97.1666666666667,25.0596151694197,229.915966386555
171,176,13.7528883271232,Chlorodendraceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,22.75,34.0498592322481,55.9663865546218
171,177,1.23575994110983,Chlorophyceae,FALSE,28.4091750097963,38.9395833333333,27.7912950392414,93.781512605042
171,178,1.23575994110983,Trebouxiophyceae,FALSE,28.4091750097963,26.4375,27.7912950392414,66.5546218487395
163,179,16.0818205238302,Amphidinium,FALSE,44.4909955336265,63,36.4500852717114,151.260504201681
163,180,8.97836128192615,Gymnodiniales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,70.625,32.8983556507594,169.411764705882
163,181,16.0818205238302,Prorocentrum,FALSE,44.4909955336265,76.5,36.4500852717114,183.025210084034
163,182,8.97836128192615,Peridiniales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,82.0625,32.8983556507594,195.126050420168
163,183,12.5171283860134,Pyrocystaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,66,34.667739202803,157.310924369748
159,184,8.97836128192615,Cryptomonadales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,5.5,32.8983556507594,15.1260504201681
178,185,12.5171283860134,Chlorellaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,27.875,34.667739202803,69.5798319327731
177,186,12.5171283860134,Protosiphonaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,36.5,34.667739202803,89.2436974789916
177,187,7.87904983431387,CS clade,FALSE,36.2882248441102,45.31875,32.3486999269533,111.932773109244
156,188,8.97836128192615,Oscillatoriales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,2.5,32.8983556507594,7.56302521008403
175,189,12.5171283860134,Lithodesmiaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,96.75,34.667739202803,226.890756302521
175,190,5.40644974235549,Biddulphiophycidae,FALSE,33.8156247521518,99.75,31.1123998809741,235.966386554622
174,191,8.97836128192615,Thalassiosirales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,117.5,32.8983556507594,281.344537815126
174,192,16.0818205238302,Chaetoceros,FALSE,44.4909955336265,126,36.4500852717114,299.495798319328
174,193,8.97836128192615,Coscinodiscales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,114.5,32.8983556507594,273.781512605042
158,194,10.6753707814747,Euglena,FALSE,44.4909955336265,9,39.1533101428892,24.2016806722689
172,195,7.1106786436579,Fragilariaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,109.125,37.3709640739808,260.168067226891
172,196,3.57191153957067,Licmophorales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,103,35.6015805219372,245.042016806723
190,197,10.6753707814747,Odontella,FALSE,44.4909955336265,100.5,39.1533101428892,238.991596638655
173,198,2.57379774098196,Cocconeidales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,134.75,36.1006374212315,313.109243697479
173,199,9.677256982886,Amphora,FALSE,44.4909955336265,138.5,39.6523670421835,322.18487394958
173,200,2.57379774098196,Naviculales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,142.166666666667,36.1006374212315,331.260504201681
173,201,6.11256484506919,Bacillariaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,151,37.8700209732751,352.436974789916
173,202,2.57379774098196,Cymbellales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,146,36.1006374212315,340.336134453781
187,203,1.09931144761228,Sphaeropleales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,39.75,36.8378805679164,96.8067226890756
187,204,1.09931144761228,Chlamydomonadales,FALSE,37.3875362917225,50.8875,36.8378805679164,124.033613445378
168,205,4.34973456544055,Isochrysidaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,15.5,38.7514361130894,39.327731092437
198,206,7.10345924190403,Cocconeis,FALSE,44.4909955336265,135.5,40.9392659126745,316.134453781513
180,207,3.53876710408723,Kareniaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,71.75,39.1569198437661,172.436974789916
180,208,3.53876710408723,Gymnodiniaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,69.5,39.1569198437661,166.386554621849
182,209,3.53876710408723,Heterocapsaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,84.75,39.1569198437661,201.176470588235
182,210,3.53876710408723,Peridiniaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,82.5,39.1569198437661,196.638655462185
200,211,7.10345924190403,Navicula,FALSE,44.4909955336265,143.5,40.9392659126745,334.285714285714
196,212,3.53876710408723,Ulnariaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,104,39.1569198437661,248.067226890756
202,213,7.10345924190403,Cymbella,FALSE,44.4909955336265,147,40.9392659126745,343.361344537815
204,214,3.53876710408723,Dunaliellaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,49.5,39.1569198437661,121.008403361345
204,215,7.10345924190403,Chlorococcum,FALSE,44.4909955336265,51.5,40.9392659126745,127.058823529412
204,216,3.53876710408723,Chlamydomonadaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,54.55,39.1569198437661,133.109243697479
203,217,3.53876710408723,Scenedesmaceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,41.5,39.1569198437661,101.344537815126
191,218,7.10345924190403,Skeletonema,FALSE,44.4909955336265,116.5,40.9392659126745,278.319327731092
191,219,3.53876710408723,Thalassiosiraceae,FALSE,40.9263033958097,118.5,39.1569198437661,284.36974789916
207,220,3.56469213781681,Karenia,FALSE,44.4909955336265,72.5,42.7086494647181,175.46218487395
209,221,3.56469213781681,Heterocapsa,FALSE,44.4909955336265,85.5,42.7086494647181,204.201680672269
183,222,3.56469213781681,Alexandrium,FALSE,44.4909955336265,67,42.7086494647181,160.336134453782
201,223,3.56469213781681,Cylindrotheca,FALSE,44.4909955336265,149.5,42.7086494647181,347.899159663866
201,224,3.56469213781681,Nitzschia,FALSE,44.4909955336265,152.5,42.7086494647181,355.46218487395
195,225,3.56469213781681,Fragilaria,FALSE,44.4909955336265,112,42.7086494647181,269.243697478992
195,226,3.56469213781681,Synedra,FALSE,44.4909955336265,109.5,42.7086494647181,261.680672268908
212,227,3.56469213781681,Ulnaria,FALSE,44.4909955336265,105,42.7086494647181,251.09243697479
216,228,3.56469213781681,Chlamydomonas,FALSE,44.4909955336265,56.1,42.7086494647181,137.647058823529
176,229,3.56469213781681,Tetraselmis,FALSE,44.4909955336265,23.5,42.7086494647181,58.9915966386555
185,230,3.56469213781681,Chlorella,FALSE,44.4909955336265,30.5,42.7086494647181,77.1428571428571
217,231,3.56469213781681,Scenedesmus,FALSE,44.4909955336265,45,42.7086494647181,110.420168067227
217,232,3.56469213781681,Coelastrella,FALSE,44.4909955336265,42,42.7086494647181,104.36974789916
189,233,3.56469213781681,Lithodesmium,FALSE,44.4909955336265,97.5,42.7086494647181,231.428571428571
228,234,4.99731300509615,unclassified Chlamydomonas,FALSE,49.4883085387227,58.5,46.9896520361746,142.18487394958
230,235,5.08439675933544,unclassified Chlorella,FALSE,49.575392292962,32.5,47.0331939132942,81.6806722689076
231,236,5.34049174713122,unclassified Scenedesmus,FALSE,49.8314872807578,46,47.1612414071921,114.957983193277
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.misc}
\begin{document}\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  conns/.initial=,
  node every node/.style={name=\nodeID, at={(\angle:\radius)}},
  node TRUE/.style={
    shape=circle, node contents=\nodeLabel,
    /utils/if={and(\angle>90,\angle<270)}
      {rotate=180+\angle, anchor=east}
      {rotate=    \angle, anchor=west}},
  node FALSE/.style={shape=coordinate, node contents=},
  do/.style 2 args={
    insert path={
      (#1) arc[start angle=\GET{#1}{angle},
               end   angle=\GET{#2}{angle},
               radius     =\GET{#1}{radius}] -- (#2)}},
  scale=.25, thick]
\newcommand*\GET[2]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/conns/#1/#2}}
\csvreader{\jobname.csv}{
  parent = \parentID,
  node   = \nodeID,
  label  = \nodeLabel,
  isTip  = \isTip,
  x      = \radius, % we use a better macro name than \x
  angle  = \angle
  % what are these?
%  y      = \y,
%  branch.length=\branchLength,
%  branch = \branch,
}{
  \node[node every node, node \isTip];
  \tikzset{
    conns/\nodeID/angle/.initial/.expanded=\angle,
    conns/\nodeID/radius/.initial/.expanded=\radius,
    conns/.append/.expanded={[do={\parentID}{\nodeID}]}}
}
\draw\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/conns};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


This worked like a charm! Thank you so much.

Probably the better that you can do in the LaTeX side for such complex trees is make the tree with R but using the tikzDevice to use the LaTeX fonts and even some LaTeX commands inside the plot.
I have no idea of how to use ggtree wisely, so consider the example only in the aspects to obtain the hybrid plot.  For simplicity, I show the code in a Quarto document.

---
format: pdf
latex-auto-install: false
---

Ggtree in  \LaTeX{} style. 

```{r}
#| include: false

library(ggtree)
# library(treeio)
library(ape)

species <- c("{\\em Homo sapiens}", "{\\em Pan troglodytes}", "{\\em Gorilla gorilla}", "{\\em Pongo abelii}", "{\\em Macaca mulatta}", "{\\em Mus musculus}", "{\\em Rattus norvegicus}", "{\\em Canis lupus}", "{\\em Felis catus}", "{\\LaTeX\\ }")

# Matriz de distancia predefinida (asegura un árbol filogenético válido)
dist_matrix <- matrix(c(
  0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.2, 0.2, 0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0, 0.8, 0.9,
  0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0, 0.9,
  0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0
), nrow=10, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(dist_matrix) <- species
colnames(dist_matrix) <- species

tree <- nj(as.dist(dist_matrix))
```

```{r}
#| echo: false

if(knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'tikz')
}

```

```{r}
#| fig-width: 4
#| fig-align: center
#| echo: false

ggtree(tree, layout="circular") + 
  geom_tiplab(aes(angle=angle), size=2.5, align=TRUE)

```


Thanks for your solution. Your solution was the most "practical" given that I was using R to generate the data anyway. But I was looking for a solution that could work without the need to have an R environment.
